# Twist on the integral test

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

I have a question regarding a slight modification of the integral test.

Suppose that $a_k = f(k)$ for some continuous function $f:[1,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$, which satisfies $f(k)\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. If $\sum_{k\geq 1} a_k$ converges, then $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(k)\,{\rm d}k$ converges.

My question is whether or not it's true obviously; I feel that it's not true because it doesn't say that $f(k)$ has to be a decreasing function like it does in the integral test, it only says that it has to go to 0. So, if this were to be true, why would this not be a useful test?

In contrast to what I said earlier, I've been trying to find a counterexample for a little while but can not seem to come up with one. If any of you can give me a hint for a counterexample or a hint on how to prove this statement, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x) = \frac{|\sin{\pi x}|}{x}.
$$
Then $a_k = f(k) = 0$, so the series converges trivially, but it's not hard to see that the integral diverges, since
$$
\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{|\sin{\pi x}|}{x} \ge 
\int_{k}^{k+1} \frac{|\sin{\pi x}|}{k+1} = \frac{2}{(k+1)\pi},
$$
and $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2}{(k+1)\pi}$ is a divergent (harmonic) series.

Comment: I feel really dumb... I was thinking of $\sin (k\pi /2)$... But dropped trig functions due to them being negative at times. Thank you!!!

Comment: Sorry, forgot the absolute value I wanted in there.

Comment: This sounds weird but I checked the answer on Wolframalpha and it says the integral is -0.2811 or so. However, it includes some weird Si function in the answer which I've never dealt with. How would I justify the integral diverges?

Comment: Without the absolute value, the integral does converge (by an argument similar to Leibniz alternating series test). With the absolute value, it diverges, for the reason in my post. Clearer now with a few more details?

Comment: Okay  last few thing; why did you use the bounds $k$ and $k+1$? Our bounds don't differ by 1, and how did you get the integral was $2/((k+1)\pi$? And did you make a typo changing the bottom of the integral from $x$ to $k+1$? Sorry for the questions! I'm trying to get a grasp on these ideas

Comment: Since $ f$ is not required to be monotonic, we may take$ f(k)=0$ for natural number  $k,$  but with $ I_k=\int_k^{k+1}f(x) dx$ large enough that $\sum I_k$ diverges, as in the example by mrf.

Comment: @Sorey I estimated the integral over an interval of length $1$ since that corresponds to one period of $|\sin \pi x|$, and there is no typo in the estimate. $1/x$ is decreasing, so $1/x \ge 1/(k+1)$ on the interval in question.